# How to convert Indian rupees to US dollar before passing to Paypal in virtue mart?

Tags: paypal, joomla2.5, payment-gateway, virtuemart

How to convert Indian rupees to US Dollar in `virtuemart E-Commerce site` in `Joomla` for `Paypal`. Is there a plugin for conversion, or do I have to change the code? If I have to change the code then in which file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're going to need to do that on your own.

[Here is a tutorial for creating a custom payment module](http://joomlamastery.com/6-virtuemart-development-build-custom-shipment-payment-plugin-101-part-2).  You could probably just copy the built in module and then customize to do the conversion.

For the conversion you can use the [ConvertCurrency API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ConvertCurrency_API_Operation/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin: [Currency Switcher Plugin for VirtueMart](http://cmsmart.net/virtuemart-extensions/currency-switcher-plugin-for-virtuemart)
Hope it can help you.